# how to store and parse an json response

Tags: c#, json

I'm currently trying to parse the response from this link https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1/domains
if you want more infos about GoDaddy api go to https://developer.godaddy.com/doc

Now in my program I should get this type of response :

```
[
  {
    "createdAt": "2015-06-15T13:10:43.000Z",
    "domain": "000.biz",
    "domainId": 1002111,
    "expirationProtected": false,
    "expires": "2016-06-14T23:59:59.000Z",
    "exposeWhois": false,
    "holdRegistrar": false,
    "locked": true,
    "nameServers": null,
    "privacy": false,
    "renewAuto": true,
    "renewable": false,
    "status": "TRANSFERRED_OUT",
    "transferAwayEligibleAt": "2016-07-29T23:59:59.000Z",
    "transferProtected": false
  }
,
  {
    ""createdAt"": ""2015-06-15T13:10:43.000Z"",
    ""domain"": ""000.biz"",
    ""domainId"": 1002111,
    ""expirationProtected"": false,
    ""expires"": ""2016-06-14T23:59:59.000Z"",
    ""exposeWhois"": false,
    ""holdRegistrar"": false,
    ""locked"": true,
    ""nameServers"": null,
    ""privacy"": false,
    ""renewAuto"": true,
    ""renewable"": false,
    ""status"": ""TRANSFERRED_OUT"",
    ""transferAwayEligibleAt"": ""2016-07-29T23:59:59.000Z"",
    ""transferProtected"": false
  }
]
```

and I need to parse it to get the "domain" attribute and write it.A
and this what I came up with:

```
const string WEBSERVICE_URL = "https://api.ote-godaddy.com/v1/domains?statuses=&includes=";
try
{
    var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(WEBSERVICE_URL);
    if (webRequest != null)
    {
        webRequest.Method = "GET";
        webRequest.Timeout = 12000;
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        webRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "sso-key " + api_key + ":" + api_secret);

        using (System.IO.Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
            {
                var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                if (jsonResponse == "[]")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No domains found");
                    bad = +1;

                }
                else
                {
                    var jo = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
                    var domain = jo["domain"];
                    hit = +1;
                    Console.WriteLine(api_key + ":" + api_secret + "=" + domain);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(do not worry about the other var like api_key. everything is working fine)
Unfortunately I get this error:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from
> JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path
> '', line 1, position 1.

And I want to get **EVERY** domain.
Hope someone will be able to help me, ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is an array so you need to use `JArray` instead of `JObject`.

```
JArray jo = JArray.Parse(jsonResponse);
Console.WriteLine(jo[0]["domain"]);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/tKAix8

Answer (score 3):

Create a class to represent your json. You can do this by copying the json > Edit > Paste Special > Paste JSON as Classes.

```
public class Domain
{
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
    public int DomainId { get; set; }
    public bool ExpirationProtected { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
    public bool ExposeWhois { get; set; }
    public bool HoldRegistrar { get; set; }
    public bool Locked { get; set; }
    public object NameServers { get; set; }
    public bool Privacy { get; set; }
    public bool RenewAuto { get; set; }
    public bool Renewable { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransferAwayEligibleAt { get; set; }
    public bool TransferProtected { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize

```
  var myDomain = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Domain>(jsonResponse);

...
    
  Console.WriteLine(api_key + ":" + api_secret + "=" + myDomain.Domain);
```

For an array of domains

```
  var myDomains = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Domain>>(jsonResponse);

...
    
  Console.WriteLine(api_key + ":" + api_secret + "=" + myDomains.FirstOrDefault().Domain);
```